# Android SAF Duplicate (1) (2) Files are Created on Huawei

Tags: java, android, file, duplicates, saf

I am using SAF to work with files on android, and I thought everything is working fine except that on a Huawei device running on EMUI 10 I found that files are being duplicated when I write on the output stream.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnM7i.png)

I construct manually the path to a document uri because when I use "findFile()" it takes minutes to iterate over all files I need (there are more than 1000). Comparing with File object takes less than 1 sec.

How do I construct a path Uri Manually

```
@Synchronized
fun getAsset(uuid: String): Uri =
    Uri.parse("${assetsFolder!!.uri}%2F$uuid") // assetsFolder!!.findFile(uuid).uri takes minutes
```

Now on the below method, the method "exists" returns false and when the file is created, it returns a duplicate counter at the end.

```
   @Synchronized
   fun requireAsset(context: Context, uuid: String): DocumentFile {
       val uri = getAsset(uuid)
       val doc = toDocumentFile(context, uri)
       return if (doc.exists())
           doc
       else {
           return assetsFolder!!.createDirectory(MIME, uuid)!!
       }
   }

    fun toDocumentFile(context: Context, uri: Uri): DocumentFile =
        try {
            DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri)!!
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            DocumentFile.fromFile(File(uri.path!!))
        }
```

Since "exists()" returns false, I try to create a file with the specified UUID but the result would be duplicate file. When I check using the File Manager, I can see both files there (File A and File A (1)).
Sometimes, "exists()" works properly I guess since I do not get a duplicate counter, but very rare. And this issue came up on an Huawei EMUI 10 Device.

requestLegacyExternalStorage is also enabled
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: Have you got any solution for this? I am facing this issue on Xiaomi.